# Convert jQuery to pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems trying to convert this piece of code from `jQuery` into pure `JavaScript`.

I've wrote everything down in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ7A6/) as example.

The script is

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $pageID = $(this).attr('name');
    var htmlString = $('#' + $pageID).html();
    $('#1').html(htmlString);
});

$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".button").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    $(this).delay(50).css('background-position', '0px -40px');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[name='page1']").trigger('click');
});
```

For the first block I've used

```
function changeNavigation(id){
    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}
```

And in each `<div id="button">` added `onclick="changeNavigation(id);"` replacing `id` with `page1` `page2` etc for their respective buttons.
Which seems to work fine. The problem is the second block of code.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById("button").style.background-position="0px -40px";
```

Changing the `class` to an `id` attribute, just to test it, but it doesn't work.
What could be the problem? Is it that pure JS doesn't support `background-position`?

Also, as last thing, is it possible to use `.innerHTML` to write JS code?
I've tried using both JS and jQuery to write Scripts and despite both writing the same exact thing, the written code didn't work with `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Your jQuery code uses a class selector (`.button`), so `getElementById()` definitely isn't the correct function.

Comment: Why have you binded two different clicks on same class? I mean, you cna perform the same task within a single event binding as well!

Comment: @Marcus, you've got a point! Thank you.

Comment: @Anthony Grist Yeah, I know. It's why I tried to change the classes to ids instea.

Comment: @Marian Well, IDs need to be unique, so trying to use multiple `<div id="button">` elements isn't going to work. There's [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), then you'd have to iterate over the returned collection and modify the style of each one individually.

Comment: Maybe first fix the bugs in your jQuery code… The `trigger()` is ugly, the `.delay()` does not work, and you should not copy html strings around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`style.backgroundPosition`

instead of

```
style.background-position
```

Thanks to Anthony Grist.

You have used class not ID. So It would be something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].style.backgroundPosition="0px -40px"
```

Comment: @Marian It's not going to work. Not because they've told you something incorrect (they haven't), but because what you've tried to select before that isn't correct.

Comment: It seems as it fail to select it. The console gives this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined `

Comment: Yeah, findled around with it also, found the solution. Thanks alot!
final thing, as you see I only want to change the style to the clicked button, and the rest revert to the 'default' style with position `0px 0px` so is it possible to select all of the divs and apply `0px 0px` then to the clicked one `0px -40px`?

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen is not valid in property names in JavaScript. Therefore, the CSS property `background-position` is called `backgroundPosition` in JavaScript.